# Trouble creating an if else program for calculating different parking cost for different vehicles

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm having trouble making this code work correctly. I have just learned this content (if else statements) and have to put it to work by creating a program that calculates parking costs per different vehicles. c for car ($2 per hour), b for bus ($3 per hour), t for truck ($4 per hour). This is in c programming with dev-c++ complier.

I appreciate all the feedback, thank you in advance!

```html
#include <stdio.h>

//declaration
char parkingCharge (int pc);
int pc;
int h, total, c, b, t;
char v;

int main (void)
{ 
//statements

 printf ("Enter type of vehicle (c for car, ");
 printf ("b for bus, or t for truck): ");
 scanf ("%c", &v);
 
 printf ("How long did you park: ");
 scanf ("%d", &h);
 
 total = pc;
 printf ("Your total is: %d", total);

return 0;
}

char parkingCharge (int pc)
{
//statements

 if (v == c){
    pc = 2 * h;
    }
    else if (v == b){
    pc = 3 * h;
    }
    else if (v == t){
    pc = 4 * h;
    }
return total;
}
```

Comment: parkingCharge should probably return an int (the product of rate and time)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't understand what you mean by that. I'm fairly new to programming. pc equals the product rate and time, no?

Comment: You don't even call `parkingCharge()` but if you did, your use of variables is all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

//declaration
int parkingCharge (char v, int h);
int h;
char v;

int main (void)
{
//statements

        printf ("Enter type of vehicle (c for car, ");
        printf ("b for bus, or t for truck): ");
        scanf ("%c", &v);

        printf ("How long did you park: ");
        scanf ("%d", &h);
        // You forgot to call the function parkingCharge.
        int total = parkingCharge(v, h);
        printf ("Your total is: %d\n", total);

return 0;
}
// parkingCharge should return an int value and you could pass
// v and h as parameters.
int parkingCharge (char v, int h)
{
    int pc;
    // Remember when you compare a variable with a constant char, you
    // put the constant char value between ''.
    if (v == 'c'){
           pc = 2 * h;
    }
    else if (v == 'b'){
           pc = 3 * h;
    }
    else if (v == 't'){
           pc = 4 * h;
    }
    return pc;
}
```

Comment: ...and if the vehicle is a `'k'`?

Comment: You just need to do another if. Like: else if (v == 'k') {...}. :)

Comment: No, *you* need to! Either that or initialise `pc`.

Comment: Ahh. I had thought parkingCharge would be an char, and the int would be pc. I had also forgotten about the ' ' for variable. 

Also I don't understand the why char v and int h in this  'int parkingCharge (char v, int h);' I'm not questioning your answer, but I just personally don't understand it. 

I'm learning programming from a book and some of the things are left very general, not going into much details.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Are you treating 'k' as an expected value or an unexpected value?

Comment: @Thiago seeing as OP did not mention `'k'` it must be an unexpected value. As your answer does not initialise `pc`, any unexpected vehicle type will cause undefined behaviour, as you omited to include a final `else` as a fall-through. I had hoped you would pick up my hint without having to spell it out!

Comment: @WeatherVane: I thought you were asking me how to treat the value `'k'` as an expected value. Yes, you are right. He could initialize the value pc as an undefined value or return an undefined value in an `else` statement. Thanks for the hint anyway!

Comment: @Jetser: `'c'` is not a variable. When you do `if (v == 'c')`, you are comparing a variable `v` with a constant char c. In other words, you are checking if the value of the variable is the character c. About the `int parkingCharge (char v, int h)`, check this: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/72-passing-arguments-by-value/

Comment: @Thiago my other hint was that your answer is flawed and ought to be corrected. `int pc=0;` would stop the program doing a GIGO ;-)